# Can I say "piece the puzzle"?

Tags: phrases, idioms

As in, *complete the puzzle*?

For example:

> He was unable to piece the puzzle sooner.

Comment: piece the puzzle _together_

Comment: Yep, "piece the puzzle together" is idiomatic (in US English).  Absent the "together", not so.

Comment: I've said today:"To puzzle pieces together", and it just doesn't sound right. It is missing the word "put".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've never seen **piece** used exactly that way before. I *have*, however, seen a common variation:

> He was unable to **piece** ***together*** the puzzle sooner.

I don't believe that **piece** can be used as a verb on its own—but it can be used as part of a phrasal verb.

A similar example is:

> He was unable to **tease** ***apart*** the puzzle sooner.

Here, although **tease** *is* a valid verb in its own right, **tease** is also used as part of a phrasal verb.

Comment: No, I've never seen "piece" used as a verb, other than in such as "piece together". However I think it would be unusual to see it used it in a literal sense, as with a jig-saw puzzle. It is more often used metaphorically, as in "The detective manage to piece-together the suspect's motive".